# Encrypt Response data and send it to the Next Request . How can i do this in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I need to Encrypt the Guid(Highlighted one) and then send it to the Next Request body.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to get guid for example to `guid` variable

Then use [__digest](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) function to encrypt (for example SHA1)

```
${__digest(SHA1,${guid},,,)}
```

> The digest function returns an encrypted value in the specific hash algorithm with the optional salt, upper case and variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt using which [algorithm](https://www.toolbox.com/security/data-security/blogs/different-encryption-algorithms-in-java-121917/)? Depending on your requirements the solutions might vary from:

1. Using [__base64Encode() custom function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup)
2. Using [__digest() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest)
3. Using [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) with your custom encryption algorithm implementation